# Cassandra Client API Most Similar to App Engine Datastore API?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, cassandra

With the announcement of the Google App Engine's new pricing model, I've realized my application will not be able to sustain itself due to the extremely high price of Google Datastore interactions.  Because it is a social game that relies on consistent and quick user input, this application simply requires far too many datstore interactions on a per-user basis to be viable (even with memcache mediating common queries and operations).

From the research I've done, it seems like the best solution would be for my team to migrate to a Cassandra-based database solution.  I've looked at the various popular APIs like Hector and Pelops, but from my initial inspection it seems these are a little too low-level for what I'm looking for.  Is there a Cassandra client API in Java that emulates the App Engine's low-level Datstore API and uses the same "Entity Group"/property model?  At the very least I would like the API to have the same "Ancestor" Entity concepts and maintain cross-group transactions in the same manner.

*EDIT* : To clarify, what I'm really looking for is a Cassandra API that supports Transactions.  As far as I can understand, transactions in a NoSQL environment are difficult, if not impossible to implement without some hierarchical groupings of "objects" (call them what you will, entities, tables, etc).  This seems to be why Hector does not implement them.

So, my question is, what is the most popular Cassandra API that implements some form of transactional systems, preferably one that uses an GAE-like Entity structure?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, per se, but it seems a beneficial approach might be to design an abstraction of the data-store needs of your application. Think of it as an internal API, designed to hide the differences of GAE and Cassandra (and maybe something else like AWS). You might find that then implementing a Cassandra version isn't so bad, and/or it gives you flexibility to change data-stores in the future.

Comment: @RichW Yeah that's exactly the approach we're taking right now. We're making a set of interfaces independent of the GAE's specific Datastore calls and moving all of the interaction with the Datastore into an implementation of that interface.  It's an immense task we really didn't want to do at this stage though, so I'd like to know which Cassandra API is the most similar so I can research it and ensure the architecture we're redesigning now won't need much modification once we make the inevitable switch.

Comment: I would've researched the GAE Channel API if I had that type of application. My apps are small to medium sized and sure I will pay 20 times more with the new pricing but it's still just a fraction of a dedicated server or a physical hosting cost since I only use very standard HTTP get and/or post. I heard about the Channel API and I think it can do these types of interactions, sorry if I'm mistaken but I'm guessing based on what I read.

Comment: @Nicke The Channel API does nothing to change the fact that the data a user sends/receives needs to be persisted somewhere.  The _Memcache_ API actually mitigates our numerous "refresh" Datastore actions, but because of the transient nature of all data stored there, the fact remains that any "updated" data needs to be sent to the Datastore consistently and constantly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see hector-object-mapper? https://github.com/rantav/hector/tree/master/object-mapper

Lightweight, annotation driven persistence for Apache Cassandra via Hector. For more docs on Hector usage, see: http://hector-client.org

Comment: Hector certainly seems to be the most popular Cassandra API for Java, but from what I've read it has no support/plans for grouping its object mappings into "Entity Groups."  As far as I understand, it's difficult (if not impossible) to implement a transaction system in a NoSQL database without grouping objects.  Perhaps I should clarify my question a bit to explain that what I am really looking for is a Cassandra API that supports transactions.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1684 - We'll support them as soon as they are available :-)

Comment: Also, for some of the original research on "entity groups" and transactions in distributed systems, see:  http://research.google.com/pubs/archive/36971.pdf (the "megastore" paper and Pat Helland's Life beyond distributed transactions: www.ics.uci.edu/~cs223/papers/cidr07p15.pdf

Comment: Ah awesome!  That enhancement request is _exactly_ what I'm looking for!

Comment: Added myself to the watch list and am going to start the (long) process of educating myself enough to hopefully contribute meaningfully.

Comment: Cool - let me know if there is anything else I can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could find is [AppScale](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale) which uses Cassandra though it's unclear to me how to set-up and run the Datastore as a stand alone service without the other GAE services. I've created an [issue](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/issues/2392) for that. Technically you could use the same client library with minor tweaks(i.e. replace the datastore  URL/endpoint with your own one)